# Slow login with Active Directory on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: login, authentication, active-directory

I am running an Ubuntu 20.04 machine configured to use my organisation's Active Directory (AD) setup.

There is a significant difference in the login time depending on whether I am connected to my organisation's local network. Away from the network, login takes ~1s, whereas connected to the network it can take several minutes, sometimes even rejecting my password at first before eventually accepting it.

Presumably there is some credential caching going on when I am disconnected from the network, but this difference in login times does seem excessive.

`/var/log/auth.log` shows the following around a login event:

```
Feb 21 14:17:01 device_name CRON[16161]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Feb 21 14:17:01 device_name CRON[16161]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Feb 21 14:20:04 device_name gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=/dev/tty1 ruser= rhost=  user=user_name
Feb 21 14:20:05 device_name gdm-password]: pam_sss(gdm-password:auth): authentication success; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=/dev/tty1 ruser= rhost= user=user_name
Feb 21 14:20:07 device_name gdm-password]: gkr-pam: unlocked login keyring
```

The authentication failure from pam_unix after a wait of 3 minutes seems suspicious, but I don't know enough to properly diagnose this.

Does anyone know what could be causing such long login times when connected to the AD network?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I have ubuntu 20.04 connected to a Windows Active Directory domain.

I commented out access_provider = ad in /etc/sssd/sssd.conf

```
....
#access_provider = ad
```

Then rebooted

Now I can login without any waiting or timeouts.

Answer (score 0):

So... I found the solution to the problem (at least it is working for me and my users)
It seems that it has to do with the many many ad groups we have in our environment.

I had to add a few lines to the `sssd.conf` file.

```
ad_gpo_access_control = permissive
ignore_group_members = true
ldap_refferals = false
```

afterwards i restarted the system.
that did the trick for me. hope it helps anyone who is fighting with this problem as well

Comment: Here is a place where the configurations above are described so one knows what this means: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/windows_integration_guide/sssd-gpo